# Wait for reaction in DMs discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that waits for a reaction on a DM and then gets the reaction emoji. I'm using discord.py. My code works in a normal text channel but not in DMs I also am getting no error messages it just doesn't work!

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx, user: discord.User):
  if user != None:
    if user != ctx.author:
      players = [ctx.author, user]
      for player in players:
        message = await player.send("test")

        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('')

        def check(reaction, user):
          return user == player and str(reaction.emoji) in ['', '']

        response = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
        if str(response[0]) == "":
          await player.send(str(response[0]))
        else:
          await player.send("")
```

Many thanks in advance

**Edit:** I do not have intents enabled

Comment: Do you have Intents enabled?

Comment: If you do not have Intents enabled you need to import them into your code and activate them in the Discord Developer Portal. Please do not make edits to your post that answer a comment, instead ping the user who asked the question and give them an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for the same problem.
I got the solution
No one posted here the solution, so Im posting it here.

> **intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, message_content=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True)**
>
> **client = discord.Client(intents=intents)**

Comment: main intent is the members=True